# Separating Piwik's backend and tracking URL

Tags: php, basic-authentication, matomo

I am using a copy of [Piwik](http://www.piwik.org), which is excellent.

For <strike>paranoia</strike> additional security, I want to place Piwik's back-end in a folder that is protected by Apache basic authentication, and whose path is hidden from prying eyes.

```
 http://example.com/protected/piwik
                        ^----------------- .htpasswd protected
```

however, now the tracking code of course no longer works!

```
var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
"https://example.com/protected/piwik/" : "example.com/protected/piwik/");
```

Is there a common way of placing the Piwik back-end in a separate protected directory, but allowing the tracker to work as usual?

Answer (score 4):

There is a better solution: use .htaccess to selectively restrict access to Piwik files: http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?2,17251

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [workaround](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/ticket/656#comment:8):

> if you don't mind losing one-click updates, I think this is doable:
>
> - copy the core, libs, plugins, config, and tmp folders to a location outside of the piwik document root
> - run "find" to remove .php and .tpl files in those folders still in the document root
>     in index.php and piwik.php, manually set PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH to point to the hidden(?) folder
> - Disclaimer: untested; use a snapshot from svn (or wait for 0.4.2)
>
> We probably won't change the build/release script, but if you come up with a patch for the Updater, we'll consider it. (You might start with defining PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT, and reading a bootstrap.ini.php file, if present, to override PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH.)

more elegant solutions are still welcomed.